# Do I have to use and 'extend' eslint-plugin-react in eslintrc.js config while using and extending 'eslint-config-airbnb' already

Tags: reactjs, react-typescript, eslint-config-airbnb

I updated my Eslint rules using airbnb in my React typescript project.

My project doesn't use 'create-reac-app'. So I have to *extend* `airbnb` since I am also using and extending `airbnb-typescript`.

`eslint-plugin-react` and `eslint-plugin-react-hooks` are peer dependencies of `eslint-config-airbnb`. So do I need to extend `plugin:react/recommended'`?

I have this in the `extend` property inside eslintrc.js:

```
extends: [
    'airbnb',
    'airbnb-typescript',
    'airbnb/hooks',
    // "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
    // "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended-requiring-type-checking",
    // "plugin:eslint-comments/recommended",
    'plugin:react/recommended',
    'plugin:jest/recommended',
    'plugin:prettier/recommended',
  ],
```

To get the best out of Eslint and React, do I have to extend `'plugin:react/recommended',` or something else or can I remove it since I am using `airbnb` and `airbnb-typescript`?

And the same question I have with extending yes or no `'plugin:react-hooks/recommended'` (since `eslint-plugin-react-hooks` is also a peer dependency of `eslint-config-airbnb` as mentioned above).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you don't need to add `plugin:react/recommended` since you are using [airbnb](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-config-airbnb#:%7E:text=Our%20default%20export%20contains%20most%20of%20our%20ESLint%20rules%2C%20including%20ECMAScript%206%2B%20and%20React). Same with `plugin:react-hooks/recommended` if you use `airbnb/hooks`.